# Is self-immolation murder?

Tags: the-buddha, beginner

Buddhism teaches prohibits murder, but some Buddhist monks self-immolate. Is this inline with Buddhist teachings or contrary to them?

Answer (score 1):

Human life is very rare and precious. Also when doing this the chances are that your last thought will not be good leading to rebirth in a lower relm. So in my opinion and general consensus in my tradition is that this should not be done. Also in doing this the following conditions of killing is met:

- You know that yourself is a living being
- You device a method to for self immolate
- You follow through with the intention
- As a result you die